# Add Text and lines of grid in group in fabric js canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I Followed Below snippet for adding a line into a group.

Now I want to add `fabric.Text` between the lines of groups.

I try to add text and line as a group but it gets fail.

It gives me an error of coordinates like  `o.setCoords is not a function`

Any help will be helpful.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
let gridSize = 15;

$("#addAsGroup").click(() => {
    canvas.clear();
    let separateLines = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < canvas.getWidth() / gridSize; i++) {
        let horizontalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [i * gridSize, 0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth()], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        let verticalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth(), i * gridSize], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        separateLines.push(horizontalLine);
        separateLines.push(verticalLine);
    }
    
    // add lines to group
    let group = new fabric.Group(separateLines);
    canvas.add(group);
});

$("#addAsSeparateObjects").click(() => {
    canvas.clear();
    let separateLines = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < canvas.getWidth() / gridSize; i++) {
        let horizontalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [i * gridSize, 0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth()], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        let verticalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth(), i * gridSize], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        separateLines.push(horizontalLine);
        separateLines.push(verticalLine);
    }
    separateLines.forEach((line) => {
        canvas.add(line);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="addAsGroup">AddAsGroup</button>
<button id="addAsSeparateObjects">AddAsSeparateObjects</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let group = new fabric.Group([...separateLines,text]);` create a group with text or directly add to canvas according to your function.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
let gridSize = 15;
var text = new fabric.Text('Grid',{left:canvas.width/2,top:canvas.height/2})

$("#addAsGroup").click(() => {
    canvas.clear();
    let separateLines = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < canvas.getWidth() / gridSize; i++) {
        let horizontalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [i * gridSize, 0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth()], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        let verticalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth(), i * gridSize], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        separateLines.push(horizontalLine);
        separateLines.push(verticalLine);
    }
    
    // add lines to group
    let group = new fabric.Group([...separateLines,text]);
    canvas.add(group);
});

$("#addAsSeparateObjects").click(() => {
    canvas.clear();
    let separateLines = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < canvas.getWidth() / gridSize; i++) {
        let horizontalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [i * gridSize, 0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth()], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        let verticalLine = new fabric.Line(
            [0, i * gridSize, canvas.getWidth(), i * gridSize], {
                stroke: '#000'
            });
        separateLines.push(horizontalLine);
        separateLines.push(verticalLine);
    }
    separateLines.forEach((line) => {
        canvas.add(line);
    })
    canvas.add(text)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="addAsGroup">AddAsGroup</button>
<button id="addAsSeparateObjects">AddAsSeparateObjects</button>
```

Comment: Showing this error : Uncaught TypeError: o.setCoords is not a function.

Comment: let group = new fabric.Group([...separateLines,text]);
what does ... stands for.?

Comment: @Rizwan It creates another array, alternatively you can push text to separateLines array and create a group.

Comment: let group = new fabric.Group([separateLines,text]); gives me error like i said

Comment: let group = new fabric.Group([...separateLines,text]); successfully added.

Comment: @Rizwan ... is spread operator, accept answer if it works, cheers ;)

Comment: @DurgaI have added id to text object, but when I try to setactiveobject(id), it gives me error like, Cannot read property 'set' of undefined. can you help in that?

Comment: @Rizwan what is setactiveobject function? Can you create another question with your code?

Comment: canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item($(this).attr('data-id'))); by selecting textbox i active the text object in canvas grid.

Comment: @Rizwan what value you are getting `canvas.item($(this).attr(data-id)))`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173371/discussion-between-rizwan-and-durga).